# Voice via cell phone and screen share via laptop with Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'd like to call people with my cell phone teams app because it makes it easy to use my AirPods. But if they want to share the screen, it's to small on the cell phone display. I would like to get the shared screen on the laptop while keeping the voice connection on the cell phone.

If it's a teams meeting this is easy. I just connect from my laptop and the cell phone to the meeting and switch off the voice on the laptop.

But I cannot find a way to do this with when calling single people.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you use the AirPods on the laptop?

Comment: I also get a lot of phone calls on the cell phone. So I would have to switch the bluetooth connection between cell phone and laptop very often. That's not really convenient.